# XHR to different port fails in edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm trying to run a webapp on localhost (port 9000) which talks to an API, also on localhost (port 8882). This works fine in Chrome, FF and IE9, but in edge, every XHR yields the following error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd
```

I've tried setting internet security settings to the lowest level, and adding localhost to the trusted sites, but without results.

Why am I getting this error, and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but switching the API to port 9001 instead of 8882 fixed the problem. By the way, I ran into a similar issue on Safari on Mac, solved by the change as well.